# Find a positive constant $C_1 \geq 0$ such that ....

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces, continuity, normed-spaces

Here $x = (x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$,

Consider the matrix  $$A= \ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} \end{array} \right)$$
as a linear ma from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Find a positive constant $C_1 \geq 0$ such that $$\|Ax\|_1 \leq C_1\|x\|_1$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
Conclude From here that the linear map $A$ is continuous.

Now I know that you must use $$\|Ax\|_1 = |a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2|+|a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2|$$ to get to 
$$=(a_{11}+a_{21})|x_1|+(a_{12}+a_{22})|x_2|$$
$$\leq M(|x_1|+|x_2|) = M\|x\|_1$$

From this point on I am unsure how to determine $C_1=M$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Missing two terms of the form $\left| {{a}_{11}}{{x}_{1}}+{{a}_{12}}{{x}_{2}} \right|\le \left| {{a}_{11}} \right|\left| {{x}_{1}} \right|+\left| {{a}_{12}} \right|\left| {{x}_{2}} \right|$ near the end there.

Answer (score 1):

$\|Ax\|_1 = |a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2|+|a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2| \le |a_{11}||x_1|+|a_{12}||x_2|+|a_{21}||x_1|+|a_{22}||x_2|$

Since $|x_1|,|x_2| \le ||x||_1$, we get, with $C_1:= \max\{|a_{11}|,|a_{12}|,|a_{21}|,|a_{2}|\}$:

$\|Ax\|_1 \le ||x||_1$